# how to limit only one document for every user

Tags: mongodb

I have one mongo collection like this:

```
| user_id | log | create_at |

| 1 |   "login" | 1490688500 |
| 1 |   "logout" | 1490688400 |
| 2 |   "view_xxx" | 1490688300 |
| 2 |   "cpd" | 1490688100 |
```

How can I get only one latest log for every user, such as

```
| 1 | "logon" | 1490688500 |
| 2 |  "view_xxx" | 1490688300 |
```

Comment: Hi donnior; can you show what you've tried so far, and explain how it's not working?

Comment: aggregation $sort, $group, $first

Answer (score 1):

You can use mongodb aggregation framework and you can run the following command:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
{ '$sort' : { 'created_at' : -1 } },
{ '$group' : { '_id' : '$user_id' , 'log' : { '$last' : '$log' }, 'created_at' : { '$last' : '$created_at' } } }
]
)
```

docs:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works when tried! however I need to specify every field name it the $group statement, is there one simple solution I can get the whole document with all fields included?

Comment: You can use $$CURRENT variable:

db.collection.aggregate(
[
{ '$sort' : { 'created_at' : -1 } },
{ '$group' : { '_id' : '$user_id' , 'doc' : { '$last' : '$$CURRENT' }} }
]
)

docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/